# nodejs function().anotherFunction() how they do it?

Tags: node.js

I install a library/module but I am curious how they do it

```
const modules = require('abc');
const app = new modules('123');

const client = app.f1('abcdef').f2('ghi');
console.log(client.to());

const client2 = app.f1('1111111').f2('2222');
console.log(client2.to());
console.log(client.to());
```

result is 123:abcdef-ghi

result is 123:1111111-2222

result is 123:abcdef-ghi

how they did it?

i want to create that example lib/module

please give me sample code

Comment: The idea is to return the object for every method that you want to be chainable. So here `f1` would return `app` (most likely `this` inside the function). Then `to` returns the actual underlying result.

Comment: can you give me example please

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact requirements, something like this seems to work:

```
let state = Symbol("private")

class App {
    constructor(arg) {
        this[state] = arg
    }
    f1 = arg => new App(this[state] + ":" + arg)
    f2 = arg => new App(this[state] + "-" + arg)
    to = () => this[state]
}
```

Here each of the chainable method returns a new instance of the class, each keeping the temporary result as a local state. The `to()` method returns that state.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for doing function().anotherFunction()

```
function func() {
    console.log("ran func")

    return {
        "anotherFunc": function () {
            console.log("ran another func")
        }
    }
}

func().anotherFunc()
```

You can also just return a object

```
const returnData = {
    "anotherFunc": function () {
        console.log("ran another func")
    }
}

function func() {
    console.log("ran func")

    return returnData
}

func().anotherFunc()
```

Example of use:

```
function word1(in_1) {

    return {
        "word2": function (in_2) {
            console.log(`Inputs: ${in_1} ${in_2}`)
        }
    }

}

word1("Hello").word2("World")
// Expected output: Inputs: Hello World
```